# generate tables in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello I have problems to generate the tables correctly, instead of being under the code they go up to the beginning of the page as shown below:

[image]

The code that I use as an example is the following

```
{r,echo=FALSE,size="tiny",warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
```

```
sample<-mtcars[1:4,1:3]

kbl(sample,booktabs=T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped"))
```

It prints the table correctly but the result is up to the top, what is the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran you code and did not have the same issue.

I'm currently using Rstudio v1.5.1717 with R version 4.1.2

I ran your code as an R-Notebook as a "chunk":

```
{r,echo=FALSE,size="tiny",warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}

sample<-mtcars[1:4,1:3]

kbl(sample,booktabs=T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing to echo = TRUE

```
{r,echo=TRUE,size="tiny",warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)


sample<-mtcars[1:4,1:3]

kbl(sample,booktabs=T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped"))
```

[image]